# Confusing with the exact location of a shellcode in memory?

Tags: c, shellcode, gcc

When we test a shellcode, we add it to a small C program and execute it in order to see it does the actual job we expect. But
most of the time, it crashes saying 'segmentation fault'. I got the same issue when I execute it on my Linux machine.

Here is what I got from an article.
It happened because the .code section is in read-only memory. So the program should copy to the stack itself before execution.
Then I compiled it adding `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack` and it worked perfectly.

So what is actually happening in memory when we execute a shellcode?

Comment: `-fno-stack-protector` disables canary (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340259/how-to-turn-off-gcc-compiler-optimization-to-enable-buffer-overflow). `-z execstack` makes stack executable. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178445/what-is-the-z-option-for-in-this-gcc-compiler-command)

Comment: stack canaries or stack cookies is a binary protection method where a special token is placed right before return address. If you overwrite it with your shellcode, then cookie will be damaged and program will crash.

Comment: Can I get an explanation of the memory layout when we test a shellcode using C?? Cuz I really confused how stack involve when we execute a simple C program which includes a shellcode